# A question on the study of quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In dummit and foote, it was stated that "The study of homomorphic images of G is thus equivalent to study the quotient group. I am not sure whether I understood this statement correctly. I knew if I can write down the lattice structure of G. Then using quotient group say G/N where N is normal, I can decrease amount of work to study the G by losing the "resolution" of finer details of G by modding out N by replacing G by G/N and N by 1*N. I just lost all the info of the lattice structure below N. But I still retain all the lattice structure above N except everything from G to N is modding out by N.

Comment: The quoted statement is just the theorem that $\text{im}\, \phi \cong G/\ker \phi$.

Comment: This is probably referencing the first isomorphism theorem, take a peak there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in what context you are talking about but by first isomorphism theorem, given $f:G \rightarrow H$ a group homomorphism, $im(f) \cong G/ker(f)$ so every homomorphic image of G can be described by G quotiented out by some normal subgroup of G.

Comment: If it just means that first isomorphism thm, I am fine with it. Does it also imply one can rather study G/ker to make the lattice structure above ker? I mean it looks like so to me. I do not know whether there is some more important consequences implied by this statement.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by lattice structure of an abstract group G.

Comment: Say you have a lattice of subgroups for G. Say we only have G->H->N->M->{1}. Now you mod out by some normal group N. Now you only have info that G/N->H/N->N/N=1 in G/N lattice of subgroup along G/N to N/N. So you lost info of M.